# disconnected: no supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey, gssapi-with-mic)

Tags: ssh, putty

I don't know what is happening.

I have been able to connect to the server for a couple of days without problems and suddendly I got a frozen window using putty. After that, each time I try to connect, I receive this message:

```
disconnected: no supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey, gssapi-with-mic)
```

I am using putty and puttyagent for private key. I already have uploaded the public key to the server and I was able to connect half an hour ago.

How can I check why it is failing? I haven't change the user or password or anything.

Comment: If you choose WHM free tier from AWS marketplace to create new ec2 machine, then this machine will be in centos with default user as centos. So please check your username while remotely access this machine with ssh.

Comment: Just upgrading the PuTTY utilities to the latest release did the trick in my case - no change in the public key added to authorized_keys on the server nor a change in the private key loaded into Pageant on the client was necessary. (Maybe the new version of PuTTY did some magic, but I am not aware if it.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well...

In the end, I had to delete all my keys, upload them again and wait a half an hour more or less. I don't know what happened but now it works again.

Answer (score 18):

I had the same issue after creating a Centos 7 vm using Vagrant. In the sshd_config file it said "PasswordAuthentication no". Changing that to "PasswordAuthentication yes" and a restart of sshd solved it for me.

Comment: That worked for me, thanks!

Answer (score 13):

I had a similar issue:

- in putty console, I got the message saying "Server refused our key"
- windows error message was: "PuTTY Fatal Error" - "No supported authentication methods 
  available (server sent: public key,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic)"

[image: see the screenshot of error message here]

I was able to connect to EC2 via PowerShell successfully (with .pem file) so I realized that .ppk file was wrong.

Googled for about an hour and find that when you generate the .ppk with PuTTYgen for the first time you'll see the key comment filed something like "rsa-key-20191006" and what should be there is "imported-openssh-key".

After I loaded the same .pem file, as for the first time (but DID NOT CLICK on Generate) and clicked Save Private Key and used this private key for Auth, everything worked as expected.

Comment: ... and select SSH-1(RSA) for the type.  It defaults to RSA (on mine).

Answer (score 10):

I got the same error
`disconnected: no supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey, gssapi-with-mic)` while trying to connect to an AWS EC2 instance with ssh using a PPK. The issue I had and fixed was that when I used PuTTYKeyGenerator to convert from PEM to PPK, by default it uses PPK file version 3 which is not supported by AWS EC2 and when I tried to connect with mRemoteNG I got the error, then I tried directly with PuTTYNG I got `PuTTY key format too new`:

[image]

To make it work, change in `PuTTYKeyGenerator >> Key >> Parameters for saving key files >> PPK file version: 2`  and then reconvert the PPK and should work.

Comment: This solution worked also for me with Oracle Cloud Infrastructure.

Comment: Solved my problem accessing a centos machine with mRemoteNG + putty private key.

Comment: this is what worked for me. I upgraded to the latest putty. Used the instructions to use PPK version 2 and reconverted the pem file to ppk again

Answer (score 9):

In my case updating both putty and puttygen to the latest version (0.76) solved this issue.

1. Download **latest** putty and latest puttygen from https://www.puttygen.com/#Download_PuTTYgen_on_Windows
2. In puttygen click **Load**, chose **All Files** and select your PEM file for your EC2 instance.
3. Choose **SSH-1 (RSA)** as a type of key to generate.
   [image]
4. Click on **Save private key**.
5. In putty in the **Auth** section click on browse and select your generated private key.

Answer (score 3):

I was getting this error because of wrong userid. As soon as I used ec2-user it worked. 
I was under the impression that my AWS account id is my userid. It seems ec2-user is by default the user, you should login with.

Answer (score 2):

Copy the content in your pem file and create another pem file and paste the content.
Sounds lame... but it works !!

Answer (score 2):

Just go to Putty keygen and load an existing private key from your local path where vagrant box for centos is installed (example :- ...vagrant\machines\default\virtualbox\private_key) and then choose SSH-1 (RSA) option from below and lastly click on "Save Private Key" button and save that file in your desktop or any where. Then open putty fill the ip address of machine -> go to SSH --> Auth -->Browse and provide the same key you have saved in your desktop or anywhere and then click on open.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue and this is only because of Windows Defender.
Just Goto RANSOMWARE Protection and allow your Know App like Putty or MoBaExtreme etc.

Answer (score 1):

After trying almost everything, this solved the issue for me:
I downloaded the latest version of PuTTYgen (0.77) and loaded the private key (.ppk) file. I then proceeded to [Save Private Key] and saved it under a different name.

This resolved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue while connecting to openshift Labs.
Stopped working for a new server. I had to Upload public key to OPENTLC again and it worked with the Putty

In PuTTY, under Category on the left, navigate to Connection → SSH → Auth.

On the right under Authentication parameters, click Browse and locate the private key saved from PuttyGen

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same error and this is what worked for me.

- In the Category pane, expand Connection, expand SSH, and then choose Auth.
- Complete the following: Choose Browse. Select the .ppk file that you
  generated for your key pair and choose Open.

AWS Docs reference link: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/putty.html

Answer (score 0):

I am using CPanel and I forgot to authorize the key so it kept giving me that error..then I had some caffeine and realized I needed to authorize. Problem solved!

Answer (score 0):

In my case only upgrading the putty version solved the issue. I was using 0.72 version. I downloaded the 0.79 installed from [here](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/%7Esgtatham/putty/latest.html). Ran the installer. It upgraded the version of the existing installation. It retained all my saved sessions and configurations. The same configuration that was not working earlier, started working after the upgrade, without any changes.

Answer (score 0):

I found 2 solutions for me. Either one of them works.

1. Updating Filezilla from 3.52 to 3.66
2. Using the right format in ppk key file.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add my scenario in case it helps someone, I was having trouble connecting to a newly span up ec2 aws linux 2 instance and getting this exact error: "No supported authentication methods available (server sent: gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic)" and ssh was configured correctly and keys were working on other instances. Could connect when I enabled password authentication.

After much searching and testing the issue was we are using a Directory as a Service provider called Jumpcloud and their default registration of machines changed so that "Enable Publik Key Authentication" was now unticked by default, despite it being enabled in ssh_config.

Answer (score -1):

Restarting the machine and re-installing FileZilla and then connecting again solved my issue.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30356618)

Answer (score -2):

This issue I could resolve by using .ppk file instead of .pem file.

The above worked for me.

Comment: Please highlight the additional insight this provides in comparison to existing answers, especially the one by Verica Milanovic.

Comment: many of the above answers are trying to delete something and create same file again and try. I also tried Verica's answer but that wasnt exactly what my issue although somewhat similar. I believe she eventually has tried with .pem in her response. But my comment is only about trying with ppk even when .pem is also available. It worked for me and still works! (and with .pem is still not working) so have shared. I wud be glad to share a Screenshot but am not able to do so because of your negative point. Can you please highlight what problem you saw with my solution?

Comment: I did and had already gone through it Sir.. that was the reason for asking you where the miss is? I still see my post as a solution (infact straight forward solution) where I tried to keep it short and direct to the point unlike others here. But if you still insist, I will delete it? :) wont gain much or loose anything by doing this. thanks again!

Comment: Now that I removed the fluff I realised that you are actually proposing the opposite of the upvoted answer I confused this with. Sorry.